# WordPress Migration: Getting 404 Errors: Only Home Page works

Tags: 404-error, migration

I just migrated my ecommerce website (www.getfitkart.com) from shared hosting to Linode. Now only the home page is working but the other pages are not getting served. I am getting the following error on all other pages like say, http://www.getfitkart.com/privacy-policy/

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /privacy-policy/ was not found on this server.

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-permalinks-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04

The thing is that we need to allow the override *all* option in httpd.conf (location: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) for your specific hosting directory.

Answer (score 19):

Go to settings->permalinks  and click on save button to rewrite flush. And then empty your browser cache. It'll work hopefully.

Comment: This solved the problem beautifully! Thank you!

Comment: Chiming in here to say that this worked with Wordpress via Docker as well. I had scaffolded a new standard Wordpress via Docker project, imported a MySQL dump into the fresh db (which had permalinks set up), and initially all page links were broken besides the root page. I did not have to empty browser cache; I just went to "Permalinks," hit save, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes on a new server it's just the rewrite module missing from Apache config.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Chiming in here to say that this was the cause of my problem on my DigitalOcean LAMP droplet.

Answer (score 7):

Solved this problem on Linux Mint 19 / PHP Version 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 by changing:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Diverse tutorials seem not to include the change of handling that going from Apache 2.2 (CentOS 6) to 2.4 (CentOS 7) conveys. The AllowOverride All setting saved my day (CentOS 7, Apache 2.4, WP 4.9)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried numerous solutions to this problem after migrating to a new server and configuration. These options did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Dear friend after moving site : go to your phone admin 
Then choose your database.
Click on wp-option
Change raw 25 to 500
Change site url : http://www.yourwebsite.com
search -- path : change path of your upload

Save it
Login your site: www.yoursitename.com/wp-admin
Go to settings 
Then go to Permalink
Do not change anything
Just Save it.

Now try your all page.

Comment: Hey, this actually worked. Thanks!